# PostgreSQL add auto increment to empty ID column

Tags: postgresql, identity, auto-increment

I create table in PostgreSQL but I forgot to add `auto increment`.

How to alter empty `Id` column in Postgres to add `auto increment`?

Comment: There is no AUTO INCREMENT syntax in PostgreSQL; you have to choose SERIAL or IDENTITY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Starting with Postgres 10 it's recommended to use `identity` columns for this.

You can turn an existing column into an identity column using an ALTER TABLE:

```
alter table the_table
  alter id add generated always as identity;
```

If you already have data in the table, you will need to sync the sequence:

```
select setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('the_table', 'id'), (select max(id) from the_table));
```

Comment: What to do if the `id` column is new in a table so it contains NULLs? how to populate it using the identity property?

Comment: I ended up using a temp sequence to fill the gaps in the ID column.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a sequence owned by that column and set that as the default value.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int);

CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq OWNED BY mytable.id;

ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('mytable_id_seq');
```